# Extjs 3.4 : No data records in Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

i am using this code :

```
grid.render('grid');
Ext.getCmp('grid').mainBody.update('<div class="x-grid-empty">' + this.emptyText + '</div>');
```

As per the documentation

> emptyText : String
>   Default text (html tags are accepted) to display in the grid body when no rows are available (defaults to ''). This value will be used to update the mainBody:

```
this.mainBody.update('<div class="x-grid-empty">' + this.emptyText + '</div>');
```

for me it shows

> Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Please help

Comment: What is `this`? We may need more code to go on but it looks like whatever `this` is doesn't contain a definition of `mainBody`

Comment: i was trying this ,,  but later i come to know about deferEmptyText : false

and emptyText :'no data found' ..... need to write them in viewConfig{}.

Comment: show us your `grid` class to explain the reason behind this error. Only can be said through the piece of code you put above is that `mainBody` does not refer a rendered object.

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet, `render` is asynchronous. Therefore, `mainBody` does not yet exist when it is called on the next line.

```
grid.render('grid');
 Ext.getCmp('grid').mainBody.update('<div class="x-grid-empty">' + this.emptyText + '</div>');
```

Also, ExtJs should handle `emptyText` itself, so I don't get why it is necessary to update the mainBody with emptyText anyway.